# Hint on real analysis derivative problem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

This problem is a homework problem for my real analysis class. For context, we just learned the definition of differentiability. We cannot use differential equation techniques like characteristic equations, integrals, etc.

**Problem:**

Let $A>0,B \not = 0$. Show there does not exist a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following for $x \in (0,1)$:

1) $f''(x)=Af(x)$

2) $f(0)=f(1)=B$

3) $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f'(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f'(x)$

**What I have done:**

I believe the goal is to prove these statements implicate that $f$ is discontinuous at some point in $[0,1]$. I figured that there must exist $c \in (0,1):f'(c)=0$. I *think* I should try to show that there must exist $d \in (0,1):f''(d)=0$. Then $f''(d)=Af(d)=0$, and maybe show that $f(d)>0$, thereby creating a contradiction.

Frankly, I am completely lost on this problem, though I find it really interesting! I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Where did you find this problem? I take it that using the well-known solution to the ODE $f''(x) = Af(x)$ is not the point of the exercise?

Comment: You can't really assume the hypotheses and then show that $f$ can't be continuous, since your hypothesis that $f''(x)=Af(x)$ assumes already that $f$ is differentiable and hence continuous.

Comment: @TheoBendit It is a homework problem for my real analysis class. We cannot solve any ODEs since we've only just learned the definition of differentiability.

Comment: @YiFan Yes, but I'm guessing the other statements contradict that one.

Comment: I don't have a solution yet, but the key to this problem will be that $A > 0$, since obviously the statement isn't true if we can have $A < 0$.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler Do you know any theorems about differentiability (e.g. mean value theorem)?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes I do, and that the derivative of a continuous function has the IVT property (e.g. only has non-simple discontinuities)

Comment: @SpencerKraisler FYI, that's also known as [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks :) It has a really beautiful proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** The most obvious way to do this is to just solve the differential equation
$$f''(x)=Af(x).$$
The characteristic equation is $\lambda^2-A=0$, so that the general solutions are
$$f(x)=C_1\exp(\sqrt{A}x)+C_2\exp(-\sqrt{A}x)$$
for constants $C_1,C_2$. Can you finish the rest?

Comment: I cannot. We didn't learn characteristic equations in my class, and consequently cannot use it. We've only learned the definition of differentiability.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler It would help to put that into the question. Are you just starting to learn real analysis, or are you in a differential equations class, or calculus class, or what? That would inform us about the possible approaches we are restricted to use.

Comment: You are right. I edited the post.